# Getting activity context without instantiating it?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have been struggling with this problem for two days,I am in situation where i need to use a method in `ActivityB`  from `ActivityA` . The problems lays in getting the context of A i have tried many solutions like:

```
static ActivityA activityA;
```

In `onCreate` state:

```
activityA = this;
```

and add this method:

```
public static ActivityA getInstance(){
   return   activityA;
}
```

In `ActivityB`, call

```
ActivityA.getInstance().myFunction(); //call myFunction using activityA
```

it did not work out because this need the `ActivityA` to be instantiated in order to pass its context to A but this is not accomplishable in my case is there any way of getting an activity's context without switching activities .
my question might turn out to be simple or intuitive but im new to this concept , thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to call any method from Activity A from Activity B then you must declare that method into any non Activity Class and by Passing Context and required parameter from both Activities you can use it from both Activities or simply create object of Activity A and call your method by passing Context of Activity B.

Comment: @ChetanJoshi Can you give me a simple code example?I have tried making an interface with the method that i want to use and i implemented it in the class where i want to use it but i ended up in situation where i need to switch to the activity that contains the method in order to pass its context which i can not do in this case

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to have common functionality in both activities, you can create `BaseActivity` that `extends Activity` and define your method in that and extend `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` by `BaseActivity` then you can access methods.
You can do it like this,

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
  public void myFunction()
 {
  ...
 }
}
```

And do this for other activities:

```
public class ActivityA extends BaseActivity
{
 public void someMethod()
 {
   myFunction();   // you can call function here directly
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extent class A using Class B simply

**OR**

```
public static ActivityA activityA;
```

In onCreate state:

```
{
activityA = this;
}
```

Outside Oncreate

```
public myFunction{
}
```

and in ActivityB call

```
activityA.myFunction();
```

Comment: thanks for replying,since my app wont be switching to A activity (B will be opened by launch where A wont be) onCreate wont be invoked thus the context will not be passed to B,any other solutions?

Comment: You could extent class A using Class B simply

Answer (score 0):

Here I Created Two Classes Consider as Activities , And Then Created one Public `methodA()` in class `Activity_A` , then Created Class `Activity_B`  and Created `methodB()` , And Created Object of `Activity_A` and Called `methodA()` by passing context of Activity `Activity_B`  .

```
        class Activity_A{
            public void methodA(Context context){
                Toast.makeText(context,"methodA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        class Activity_B{
            public void methodB(){
                Activity_A activity_a = new Activity_A();
                activity_a.methodA(Activity_B.this);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for replying , unfortunately this gave me a NullPointerException on this line:   activity_a.methodA(Activity_B.this);

Comment: If you are using any view or sub methods from method of Activity_A which uses Context of Activity_A  then it may happens .So  make sure your calling method does not update any UI component (views ) of Activity_A .Bcoz now you have passes Context Of Current Actvity_B.

Comment: Add your method in your Question , So its clear , What are you want to do.

Comment: my code have gone into a real mess it would look intimidating to post it here since its too nested ,basically i have  a method in activity  A which deletes saved files and the other activity (B activity ) has a listview displaying all the saved text files(they are notes actually) so when i long press the notes in B activity i get delete option and im trying to call the delete method from A when the user choose to press the delete icon , i did achieve this by inheritance as others suggested which is great in this case, but still wondering how to get a context without having to open the activity

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1) Add the static keyword to your shared methods

OR

2) You can try reflection.

For reference follow the link:
[What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)